# Get msg = (#100) link is not properly formatted when posting to /me/feed on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, applinks

I am tearing my hair out trying to get my app to work with AppLinks on iOS. When I try to post to /me/feed I get back an error and a "msg = (#100) link is not properly formatted". I know it "should" work as I wrote a 2nd to invoke my app that call UIApplication:openURL and it works just fine. I know that my link is properly formatted. Here is the code that does the post:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
parameters:params  HTTPMethod:@"POST"
completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id     result, NSError *error) {
```

params are:
    (lldb) po params
    {
    app = numericaltestid;
    link = "urlschemestring://play/content?contentId=1";
    message = cohggjfkhf;
    picture = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/opmApx_el-U/mqdefault.jpg";
    }

In the plist is the following:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>CFBundleURLName</key>
<string>com.companyname.Appname</string>
<key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>fbnumericaltestid </string>
</array>
</dict>
</array>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>numericaltestid </string>
<key>FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix</key>
<string>urlschemestring </string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>Appname</string>
```

Comment: The link should start with http or https. Then you use app links to make that link open directly in your app

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue from a Django application, but the cause was that I was providing a “local” URL (`/path/to/object`) instead of a full URL (`http://domain.name/path/to/object`); the full URL prefix must be included in the FB application settings.